# Total 6 digit numbers where a digit is repeated exactly 4 times.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Need to find the total numbers out of all 6 digit numbers where a digit is repeated exactly 4 times in the number.

Eg. 111122, 111123 is valid
But 111121 is not valid.

Comment: What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Solve it by making cases

Comment: NB: there will be special cases for the digit 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's construct all such numbers, starting from the left:
The first digit can be chosen in $9$ ways, as $0$ is forbidden.

case 1: this is also the repeated digit: then we can pick $5 \choose 3$ remaining places where that same digit will appear. And finally we are left with picking out of $9$ remaining digits for the 2 remaining positions without restrictions ($9^2$).

case 2: this is not the repeated digit: we have to pick $5 \choose 4$ remaining positions where the repeated digit (for which we have  9 choices left) has to appear. We are left with one position with a digit unequal to the repeated one (so 9 options).

So I get $9({ 5 \choose 3}\cdot 9^2 + 9\cdot{5 \choose 4}\cdot 9)= 9^3(10+5)=10935$ options.

Comment: My brute force Python script confirms this answer, BTW.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. 
Can you also help me with finding total of such 6 digit numbers less than a given number x. 
Eg. x = 354875
111122, 222215, 333354 are valid 
366663, 999985, 525525 are not valid.

Comment: @AmanPradeepGupta some extra cases maybe? The first digit has to be $1,2,3$ but with $3$ we get a condition on the second etc.

Comment: I would frame it as to find a total of all 6 digit numbers that are less than 354875, where a digit is repeated exactly 4 times (can be in any order). 

For **354875** it comes out to be : **3285**
For **547578** it comes out to be : **5253**
For **800000** it comes out to be : **8505**
For **900000** it comes out to be : **9720**

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid cases by recognizing that $\frac 9{10}$ of a string of random digits won't have a leading zero

Thus, [Choose and place quadruple]$\times$[Place different digit(s) in remaining two slots]$\times\frac9{10}$

$10\times \binom64 \times 9^2 \times \frac9{10} = 10,935$

Comment: Thanks, this is great. 
Can you also help me with finding total of such 6 digit numbers less than a given number x. 
Eg. x = 354875
111122, 222215, 333354 are valid 
366663, 999985, 525525 are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean any digit combinations as "numbers":

$10\times1\times1\times1\times1\times9\times9+...+10\times9\times9\times1\times1\times1\times1 = 10\times9^2\times \binom64=10\times9^2\times 15=12150$

If the qualities of numbers are meant to be satisfied (leading zeros excluded), simply multiply by $9/10$ as any case that starts with a zero is to be excluded.